# CSS - Hover affecting two elements with two different background-colors

Tags: css

I have a list element with two tags inside of it, anchor tag and a span - tag.
What I'd like to achieve is that when hovering over anchor tag, the actual
background would change to black where as the span tag's background would change to green.

Is this possible with CSS3 or do I need to use JavaScript?
I won't be pasting any code here, since it's pretty straight forward.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the CSS so far:

```
#left_control_links li a {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px; padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
    font-weight: 600; float: left; width: 83%;
    color: #dfdfdf; text-decoration: none;
}
#left_control_links li a:hover {

    background: #272727;

}
span.list_total_count {

    display: inline-block; background-color: #2c2c2c; float:right; min-width: 31px;
    color: #fcfcfc ;padding: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="left_control_links">
    <li>
    <a href="subjects">Subjects
    <span class="list_total_count"><?=$total_subjects?></span>
    </a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="staff_users">Users
    <span class="list_total_count"><?=$total_users?></span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kyselyiden seuranta</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/T7cVZ/ ?

Comment: You need to demonstrate that you've tried something.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah exactly, but the problem is that the span element already have it's own background-color which is a little bit lighter than the a elements background

Comment: What do you mean? it still does not work? you should also post as small as possible piece of HTML code.

Comment: I posted the HTML part.. And I didn't get it to work with that "+" - sign

Comment: @B_CooperA it's because in my demo `span` is just the next sibling of `a`, while in your actual HTML code, it's a child of the `a` element, so you can use the selector `>` instead. Check [this updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T7cVZ/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure
See this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gWXhJ/

add the parent `:hover` and apply css added their children

```
<li>
    <a href="#text">this is link</a>
    <span>Text test</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code in question, CSS to change span background color on mouse over:

```
#left_control_links li a:hover span.list_total_count {
    background: none #aaa;
}
```

I am posting this, cause CSS specificity may have main rule in similar examples. Very good article at: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/